# MySQL Where Clause Issues

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT `location`.`building`, `location`.`classroom` FROM `schools`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `location` 
ON `location`.`location_serial` = `classroom`.`location_serial` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `rack_info` 
ON `classroom_info`.`location_serial` = `classroom`.`location_serial` 
WHERE (
    (((`location`.`building` LIKE 'SCH%')))
    AND 
    (`classroom_info`.`status` NOT IN (1, 2))
    AND 
    (
        (
            (`location`.`building` = 'SCH1' AND `location`.`classroom` != '99')
            AND
            (`location`.`building` = 'SCH1' AND `location`.`classroom` != '34')
        )
    )
)
```

I'm having a problem in my WHERE clause.

Let's say location.building can be SCH1, SCH2, SCH3, SCH4, CAB1, CAB2. I'm trying to select all of the SCH classrooms, where some classroom statuses are 1 & 2.

This all works fine

The problem arises when I try to further filter my results to exclude instances when the building is SCH1 and the classroom ID is 99, and when the building is SCH1 and the classroom ID is 34. I want to show all other classrooms across all SCH buildings (including SCH1, e.g. SCH1.98) but exclude the two specific classrooms mentioned in the SQL query above (SCH1.99 and SCH1.34)

I may also want to exclude other SCH rooms, like SCH2.24, SCH3.33 - but I want all the other classrooms to appear.

I've been looking for hours and I think I've reached the limits of my ability - all help welcome.

Comment: Shouldn't `classroom_info.status NOT IN (1, 2)` be rather `classroom_info.status IN (1, 2)`? That might be the reason why the queries from the answers don't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition:

> exclude instances when the building is SCH1 and the classroom ID is 99

can be written as:

```
NOT (`location`.`building` = 'SCH1' AND `location`.`classroom` = '99')
```

or:

```
(`location`.`building` <> 'SCH1' OR `location`.`classroom` <> '99')
```

So do this:

```
SELECT `location`.`building`, `location`.`classroom` FROM `schools`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `location` 
ON `location`.`location_serial` = `classroom`.`location_serial` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `rack_info` 
ON `classroom_info`.`location_serial` = `classroom`.`location_serial` 
WHERE
    `location`.`building` LIKE 'SCH%'
    AND 
    `classroom_info`.`status` NOT IN (1, 2)
    AND 
    (`location`.`building` <> 'SCH1' OR `location`.`classroom` <> '99')
    AND
    (`location`.`building` <> 'SCH1' OR `location`.`classroom` <> '34')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

I had actually tried this earlier in my thought process, and what it does is it excludes results such as SCH1 classroom 01, SCH1, classroom 02. It excludes all the classrooms in SCH1.

My condition is probably poorly phrased, let me update it.

Comment: How can it exclude classrooms 01 and 02? There is no condition like this in my code. Copy and paste it as it is and try it.

Comment: The only way that these classrooms are excluded is if their status is 1 or 2.

Comment: This looks to be working for me, let me play around with it for 10 mins just to be sure and I'll come back and accept your answer if so.

Comment: It works! but I don't understand how and I'd love to understand it better.

How does:
```NOT (`location`.`building` = 'SCH1' AND `location`.`classroom` = '99')```
equal
```(`location`.`building` <> 'SCH1' OR `location`.`classroom` <> '99')```

I want to exclude when the building IS SCH1 AND classroom IS 99, I don't get why the NOT OR NOT combo works here...

Comment: This is Boolean Algebra (Logic). `NOT (a AND b)` equals `(NOT a) OR (NOT b)`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll read more about that and make sure I understand this fully. Thanks a mil for your answer and taking the time to help me understand why it works.

Comment: There is even a name for this: [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ways how I would write the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE location.building LIKE 'SCH%'
  AND classroom_info.status NOT IN (1, 2)
  AND NOT (location.building = 'SCH1' AND location.classroom = '99')
  AND NOT (location.building = 'SCH1' AND location.classroom = '34')


WHERE location.building LIKE 'SCH%'
  AND classroom_info.status NOT IN (1, 2)
  AND NOT (location.building = 'SCH1' AND location.classroom IN ('99', '34'))


WHERE location.building LIKE 'SCH%'
  AND classroom_info.status NOT IN (1, 2)
  AND (location.building, location.classroom) NOT IN (
      ('SCH1', '99'),
      ('SCH1', '34')
  )
```

This makes it quite simple to add more exclusion cases.

Answer (score 1):

To "exclude instances when the building is SCH1 and the classroom ID is 99, and when the building is SCH1 and the classroom ID is 34" you can check that the building isn't `'SCH1'` or (especially when the building is `'SCH1'`) the classroom ID is not in `'34'` or `'99'`. (Assuming the classroom ID is a `varchar`, otherwise you can drop the single quotes.)

```
SELECT `location`.`building`,
       `location`.`classroom`
       FROM `schools`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `location` 
                            ON `location`.`location_serial` = `classroom`.`location_serial` 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `rack_info` 
                            ON `classroom_info`.`location_serial` = `classroom`.`location_serial` 
       WHERE `location`.`building` LIKE 'SCH%'
             AND `classroom_info`.`status` NOT IN (1,
                                                   2)
             AND (`location`.`building` <> 'SCH1'
                   OR `location`.`classroom` NOT IN ('34',
                                                     '99'));
```